# How to convert int array to Mat object in Javacv

Tags: java, typeerror, javacv, mat

I am new in javacv I was doing face recognition using FaceRecognition class:
I have array of int named "labels" and Matvector "images".
When I use facerecognition.train(images, labels), it gives me an error that int array cannot be converted to Mat.
So any one please tell me that how can I convert that int array object to Mat object.
here is my code

```
File[] imageFiles = root.listFiles(pngFilter);

    MatVector images = new MatVector(imageFiles.length);

    int[] labels = new int[imageFiles.length];

    int counter = 0;
    int label;

    IplImage img;
    IplImage grayImg;

    for (File image : imageFiles) {
        img = cvLoadImage(image.getAbsolutePath());

        label = Integer.parseInt(image.getName().split("\\-")[0]);

        grayImg = IplImage.create(img.width(), img.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

        cvCvtColor(img, grayImg, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        images.put(grayImg);


        labels[counter] = label;

        counter++;
    }

    IplImage greyTestImage = IplImage.create(testImage.width(), testImage.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

    //FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createFisherFaceRecognizer();
     FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createEigenFaceRecognizer();
    // FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createLBPHFaceRecognizer()

    faceRecognizer.train(images, labels);
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: new Mat(intArray) ... does this help cause the constructor takes an array of integers.